# I can not update database using php

Tags: php, mysqli

For some reason I am can not update my database. Can anyone spot what I am doing wrong ?
Here is the code.

.......

```
session_start();

    $user = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['user']);
    $email = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['email']);

.......

 if ($errorMessage == "") {
// ---- ---- ---- ---- ---- ---- ---- ---- ---- ----- CHECKING SERVER
        include('connect.php');
        if (isset($user)) {
            $sql = "UPDATE hookers ".
            "SET user= ´$user´".
            "WHERE email= ´$email´" ;
            mysqli_query($con, $sql) or die("Can´t find user". mysql_error());
            print "user updated";
            mysqli_close($con);
        }
    }

connect.php file 

$host = 'localhost';
$username = 'root';
$password = '';
$db = 'putas';

$con = mysqli_connect($host, $username, $password) or die("Can´t connect to server");
mysqli_select_db($con, $db) or die("Can´t connect to database");
```

Whenever I run the script it prints "Can´t find user". The variables $user & $email have the right data as I have checked it.

I would appreciate any help you guys can provide me.

Thanks in advance.

Oliver Tangari

Comment: `´` is not the same as `'`. You most likely copy pasted from a blog/site that prettifies quotes.

Comment: Not to mention the fact that you're mixing MySQL APIs. This isnt rum & coke ;-)

Comment: thank you for your reply, I know this is not rum & coke that´s why I am trying to learn new things everyday and get better at it.

Answer (score 0):

You need to change all instances of `´` to `'`.

Answer (score 0):

Your Sql Query Will Be like this:--

```
$sql = "UPDATE hookers ".
            "SET `user`= '$user'".
            "WHERE `email`= '$email'" ;
```

Hope it helps you...

Answer (score 0):

Use `'` single quote not `

```
$sql = "UPDATE hookers ".
            "SET user= '$user'".
            "WHERE email= '$email'" ;
```

Answer (score 0):

As already mentioned the problem is `´`

Why don't you use PDO and parameter binding instead? This won't give you this type of errors in the future.

```
<?php
// configuration
$dbtype     = "sqlite";
$dbhost     = "localhost";
$dbname     = "test";
$dbuser     = "root";
$dbpass     = "admin";

// database connection
$conn = new PDO("mysql:host=$dbhost;dbname=$dbname",$dbuser,$dbpass);

// new data
$user = 'Belén Esteban';
$email = 'belenesteban@telecinco.es';

// query
$sql = "UPDATE hookers 
        SET user=?
        WHERE email=?";
$q = $conn->prepare($sql);
$q->execute(array($user,$email));

?>
```

Comment: Sry if I missed out this post before. Thx anyway for your help. I will try your method now.